# Control Point finder for regular Images

Tags: linux, image-processing, command-line, image-recognition

I'm looking for a program similar to Hugin's `cpfind` or `align_image_stack`  that works for regular Pictures which are not Photos.

It should be able to detect similar points from two overlapping images

- without needing Information like FOV or Projection
- with images of different size and resolution

A Python Script would be alright.

Comment: Just as clarification for those where it doesn't ring a bell: that's to identify those "similar points" for panorama stitching or HDR processing, right? And you probably have the problem of not knowing the FOV/lens-data as they're not saved in Exif (e.g. pictures from a smartphone)?

Comment: In my case its about satellite images. But I just wanted to ask for any kind of images

Comment: Thanks – so stitching it is. Makes the context of "control points" clearer IMHO :)